Is there a way to make the ClamAV server connect for my Antivirus Project so I can use it to scan files for viruses?
I've been having issues with scanning the eicar file by using a library called nClam in my project. I'm programming using C# and I cannot seem to be able to get my program to write in a listBox in my window forms application that its found a virus in the eicar file. Maybe I'm missing something to add to my code or a resource of some sort? When attempting to scan this file, the listBox gets updated with "Error scanning - A connection attempt has failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond".
I tried to download all the resources from this link https://www.architectryan.com/2011/05/19/nclam-a-dotnet-library-to-virus-scan/ and I've applied this NuGet package to my code aswell: https://www.nuget.org/packages/nClam. Using this I hoped to be able to scan the files a user has selected, incrememnting the progress bar and in the listBox, the directory would be listed along with the file name and properties and it would indicate if the file has a virus or not.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
